# I need to link separate table IDs

Tags: mysql, reactjs

I have a dashboard where I can update, delete and create. I have 3 separated tables, Developers, Absent, Date.

Developers contains developer names and personal information. Absent is used for a segment of code, basically on certain days someone is absent. Date is mostly the same but this is for holidays instead.

I joined tables, so `absent.absent_id=developers.absent_id, date.date_id=developers.date_id`

When I create a developer I need to insert values. HOWEVER, I'm having a problem. The IDs of the tables need to be manually inputed through the database. I would like it so that If I create a new developer on the dashboard using Insert, The absent_id and date_id are ID linked between tables.

In short:
If create developer on submit, Add new Auto-incremented ID row to all 3 tables. Anyway this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with 3 SQL request, first insert new Developer and return its ID, use that to insert a new row in Absent Table and also return its ID, use both IDs to create Date row, i don't think it's related to Front-end(React) but rather a backend.
Cheers.